# Ruby URI cannot handle link-local IPv6 addresses with explicitly specified outgoing interface?

Tags: ruby, uri, ipv6, link-local

I'm trying to get done some RESTful stuff with Ruby std. libraries, 'uri' and 'net/https.' I'd like to reach link-local IPv6 address with explicitly specified outgoing interface, for example `fe80::cba7:32b1:741d:5c41%ens192`.

Whent I'm trying to create a new URI instance - I'm still receiving the same error (for both examples below):

```
URI("https://[fe80::cba7:32b1:741d:5c41%ens192]/")
URI("https://[fe80::cba7:32b1:741d:5c41%25ens192]/")
```

returns

```
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?)
```

Please do you have any idea how to handle these IPv6 link-local addresses?
Just for the reference I've tried to make a simple HTTP request, it works. So generally, Ruby has no issue with IPv6 :)

```
require 'net/https'
request = Net::HTTP.new('fe80::cba7:32b1:741d:5c41%ens192', 443)
request.use_ssl = true
request.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
request.get('/')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I've just found answer ... IPv6 scoped addressing zone is not supported in URI specification RFC3986. And Ruby URI implementation follows standards. So that's why :) 
The only way would be:

- create a new URI parser https://www.packetizer.com/rfc/rfc6874/
- require it in your code
- set URI::DEFAULT_PARSER i.e. `URI::DEFAULT_PARSER = URI::RFC6874_Parser.new`

I've found that std. Go library net/url supports RFC6874, so at least there's some inspiration for the coding of Ruby `RFC6874_Parser` :)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    u, err := url.Parse("https://[fe80::250:56ff:fe9e:76d9%25ens192]")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(u.Hostname())
}
```

returns

```
fe80::250:56ff:fe9e:76d9%ens192
```

http://godoc.burntsushi.net/src/net/url/url.go